# iOS UIWebView does not show the websites correct

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiwebview

I am creating a simple UIWebView like shown.
All works fine but the websites are corrupted. it looks like, the images arent loaded.

Curious is, that in the Browser, the same page is loading fine O_o Any Ideas?

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()
@property NSURL *adUrl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation WebViewController

-(id) initWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.adUrl = [NSURL new];
        self.adUrl = url;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.adUrl]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I've seen huge websites which loads correctly in `UIWebView`, btw you're testing this on real device? Also try to open the same website in Safari browser.

Comment: You can view the webpage source and analyse it.

Comment: real device or simulator does look the same. In the Safari Browser it looks perfectly ok with exact the same URL

Comment: okey! now open the website in Safari browser of both.

Comment: in the browser it does look good.

Comment: What is the URL to those corrupt images?

Comment: http://www1.belboon.de/adtracking/03644208fb6e021eac003c0d.html is the link I am using.

Comment: After some research and implementing the UIWebViewDelegate it looks like, that only the initial html is loading. The rest , where the images are and so on are not handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task solved. The Problem was, that an old Class which was responsible for WebCaching was disturbing the redirect and on that way it suppressed the load of baseURL objects. Thanks for givin me ideas how to solve.
Cheers